# Can't solve undefined references

Tags: c++, linker, bulletphysics

I have the following errors when compiling in Eclipse:

```
make: *** [ogre-bullet-playground] Error 1
undefined reference to `btCapsuleShape::btCapsuleShape(float, float)'
undefined reference to `btRigidBody::btRigidBody(float, btMotionState*, btCollisionShape*, btVector3 const&)'
undefined reference to `btRigidBody::btRigidBody(float, btMotionState*, btCollisionShape*, btVector3 const&)'
undefined reference to `btConvexHullShape::btConvexHullShape(float const*, int, int)'
undefined reference to `btKinematicCharacterController::btKinematicCharacterController(btPairCachingGhostObject*, btConvexShape*, float, int)'
```

These are the libraries I am using:

```
OgreMain
OIS
boost_system
OgreTerrain
BulletDynamics
BulletCollision
LinearMath
```

Does somebody knows how to fix this? The libraries are OK I think, I don't know why this isn't compiling.

Comment: Please upload your code. I think it can be helpful.

Comment: The code is almost useless in this problem, as it is a reference problem. You can do much with the code.

Comment: They're all C++ constructors that are missing.  You'll need to work out which library or libraries should be providing those constructors, and include the relevant one or ones in the link line, or maybe reorder the list of libraries.

Comment: Do you know how to check what constructors are available with the shared objects I have?

Answer (score 0):

> undefined reference to `btCapsuleShape::btCapsuleShape(float, float)'

This constructor is supposed to be defined in the `BulletCollision` library.

> These are the libraries I am using: ... BulletCollision

The most likely explanation is that you did something like this:

```
g++ -lBulletCollision ... main.cc
```

Don't do that. The order of source and object files and libraries on command line [matters](http://webpages.charter.net/ppluzhnikov/linker.html), and your order is likely wrong.

Comment: I don't think Eclipse would mess that up.